# pthread with mutex and condition variables (C++) OOP

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, conditional-statements, mutex

Hello =D I am kinda stuck with a problem, I am trying to use pthread with mutex and cond variables to implement a garage. Normally I would just do it in main, but because I want to expand my C++ skills with OOP I want to implement it as a class.

First of all, I have some method that is called with threads. However, because of the way void* work in classes I have to implement them as static or functions outside of the class.

The problem is that it seems that the mutexes and condition variables wont communicate

```
void garage::start()
{
    refresh = false;

    pthread_create(&entryThread, nullptr, entryGuardThread, this);

    for_each(carsThread.begin(), carsThread.end(), [&,this](pthread_t thread)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &carThread, this);
    });
}
```

This is in the class

```
void* carThread(void* in)
{
    garage * temp = (garage*)in;
    pthread_t uniqueThread = pthread_self();
    while(!temp->refresh) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&temp->entryLock);

        temp->carWaitingAtEntry = true;

        pthread_cond_signal(&temp->atEntry);
        while(!temp->entryOpen)
            pthread_cond_wait(&temp->atEntry, &temp->entryLock);    

        temp->carWaitingAtEntry = false;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&temp->entryLock);

        temp->waiting(1);

    }
    return nullptr;
}

void* entryGuardThread(void* in)
{
    garage * temp = (garage*)in;
    while(!temp->refresh) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&temp->entryLock);
        while(!temp->carWaitingAtEntry) 
            pthread_cond_wait(&temp->atEntry, &temp->entryLock);

        temp->entryOpen = true;
        pthread_cond_signal(&temp->atEntry);
        while(temp->carWaitingAtEntry)
            pthread_cond_wait(&temp->atEntry, &temp->entryLock);

        temp->entryOpen = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&temp->entryLock);

    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Do note that the reason that the functions are implemented as friends of the class so that I can access the private variable (I know it is stupid, but I gotta get it to work first). I have tested it and both functions refer to the same garage object....

All help is appreciated.

The Thread freezes at

```
while(!temp->entryOpen)
            pthread_cond_wait(&temp->atEntry, &temp->entryLock);
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you meant by "the mutexes and condition variables won't communicate"?  (i.e. what behavior did you observe, and how was that behavior different from the behavior you expected to observe?)

Comment: Btw it looks like all of your threads are accessing the member variable "refresh" outside of any mutex -- if "refresh" isn't a std::atomic or similar thread-safe type, that may be a race condition that can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: i meant to link a picture of some of id outputs. However, from what i observe, the thread locks at pthread_cond_wait(&temp->atEntry, &temp->entryLock);

Comment: That might be it. Brb =D

Comment: Use std::thread.

Comment: using an bool instead of refresh didn't help.

Comment: Using POSIX is part of the assignment...